# Add column in Customer grid based on module's Model

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, grid, customer-grid

Need to add a custom column in Customers grid from the status in the Module's Model.

i was using this code

config.xml

```
<adminhtml>
    <rewrite>
<customer_grid>Company_MyModule_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid</customer_grid>
    </rewrite>
</adminhtml>
```

Company/MyModuleBlock/Adminhtml/Customer/Grid.php

```
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    //This is where the problem occurs
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array(
            'mycustomtable' => 'my_custom_table'
        ),
    'mycustomtable.customer_id = e.entity_id',
    );
    //This is where the problem occurs
    parent::setCollection($collection);
}
protected function _prepareColumns()
 {
     $this->addColumnAfter('custom_status',
         array(
             'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Custom Status'),
             'index' => 'mytable_status',
             'align' => 'center',
             'width' => '20'
         ),
         'website_id'
     );


     return parent::_prepareColumns();
 }
```

The column is added and i can view it..i can populate the data from the same table(customers) but i am unable to populate data from any other table..(my_custom_table)

Thanks..

Comment: Please add more details about the issue you are facing. Are you able to add the column? Are you facing issue with populating data?

Comment: The column is added and i can view it..i can populate the data from the same table(customers) but i am unable to populate data from any other table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a side note ... as long it is not required, do not use rewrites. Adding columns can be done via events/observers ...

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
            <observers>
                <your_observer_name>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>your_model/observer</class>
                    <method>appendColumnToCustomerGrid</method>
                </your_observer_name>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
        <eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
            <observers>
                <your_observer_name>
                    <class>your_model/observer</class>
                    <method>beforeCollectionLoad</method>
                </your_observer_name>
            </observers>
        </eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

**Company/MyModule/Model/Observer.php**

```
public function appendColumnToCustomerGrid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getBlock();
    if (!isset($block)) {
        return $this;
    }

    if ($block->getType() == 'adminhtml/customer_grid') {
        /* @var $block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid */
        $block->addColumnAfter('mytable_status', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Custom Status'),
            'index' => 'mytable_status',
            'align' => 'center',
            'width' => '20'
        ), 'website_id');
    }
}
```

> used code from Jaimin Sutariya here!

```
public function beforeCollectionLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    if (!isset($collection)) {
        return;
    }

    if ($collection instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection) {
        /* @var $collection Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection */
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            array(
                'mycustomtable' => 'my_custom_table'
            ),
            'mycustomtable.customer_id = e.entity_id',
            array('mycustomtable.mytable_status') // YOUR STATUS COLUMN
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying this method but looks like there is an issue with `$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft()` everytime it trowing an error when ever i try to JoinLeft

Comment: Geting an error as follows:
`
Item (Mage_Customer_Model_Customer) with the same id "137" already exist
`

Comment: Does it work with Jaimin Sutariyas code?

Comment: It worked !! added `->group('e.entity_id')` and its working fine ... thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your **setCollection()**

```
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    //This is where the problem occurs
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array(
            'mycustomtable' => 'my_custom_table'
        ),
    'mycustomtable.customer_id = e.entity_id',
    array('mycustomtable.mytable_status') // YOUR STATUS COLUMN
    );
    //This is where the problem occurs
    parent::setCollection($collection);
}
```